# SQL Server database encryption Standard vs Web editions

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Data encryption is available in SQL Server Standard and Web editions.

The question I have on the web edition, is the SQL Server backup encrypted?

[Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16)

On this Microsoft website it states for web edition "Encrypted backup" says no.

I understand that a non encrypted database cannot have an encrypted backup, but if the database was already encrypted wouldn't the SQL Server backup also be encrypted?

I have not tested this because I am setting up new server with database encryption at rest per a customer request.

Trying to decide whether to use SQL Server Standard or Web editions. SQL Server Web edition has always worked well for our web based software and is cheaper than SQL Server Standard edition.

Any additional thoughts/advice?

Comment: _"I understand that a non encrypted database cannot have an Encrypted backup"_ - who is saying that? .That's demonstrably untrue: [SQL Server explicitly supports making encrypted backups of non-encrypted databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-an-encrypted-backup?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Encrypting a backup and encrypting data in a database are *completely* different things and completely unrelated features.

Comment: The question shows a bit of confusion that can be solved by looking at the SQL Server [features by edition comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16). The only real question seems to be whether Web edition allows encrypted backups or not. As the docs show, backup encryption isn't supported but encrypted databases are

Answer (score 1):

> but if the database was already encrypted wouldn't the SQL Server backup also be encrypted?

Yes it would be encrypted.

Web Edition supports Transparent Data Encryption, and backups of TDE databases are always encrypted.

> Backup files for databases that have TDE enabled are also encrypted
> with the database encryption key. As a result, when you restore these
> backups, the certificate that protects the database encryption key
> must be available. Therefore, in addition to backing up the database,
> make sure to maintain backups of the server certificates. Data loss
> results if the certificates are no longer available.

[Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16)

The Backup Encryption feature is specifically to create encrypted backups of non-encrypted databases.

Answer (score 0):

Web Edition does not support this.

However, you can easily meet backup encryption obligations separate from anything built into SQL Server by backing up directly to an encrypted volume (using BitLocker or even built into NTFS/Windows in a pinch), and then further using an additional encryption utility as (or before) you copy the backup file(s) to persistent storage like tape or cloud backup environment.

Comment: We recommend Bitlocker for disk encryption, over NTFS volume encryption. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/data-protection/bitlocker/, per considerations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/security-considerations-for-a-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-ver16#sa_with_least_privileges